# Grammar is LL(1) or not?

Tags: compilers, parsers

S -> AS | b

A -> SA | a

I get FIRST of S = {a,b} for S->AS
and FIRST of S = {b} for S->b

Hence FIRST(AS) ∩ FIRST (b) is not a disjoint 
This is not LL(1)

But I checked this site http://smlweb.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/start.html
and this shows the grammar is LL(1).
[image]
Here I am confused!

Is it LL(1) or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That website uses a different notation than what you assumed. This would be the correct input:

```
S -> A S | b.
A -> S A | a.
```

You entered `AS` (and `SA`) which it does not recognize as `A` followed by `S`, but as a single nonterminal named `AS`.

With that input it correctly says that the language is not $\text{LL}(1)$.